# Calling custom post type in plugin itself

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am writing a plugin in which I have below custom post type:

```
function create_post_type_contact() {
register_post_type('contact', 
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Contacts'),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'contact'),
            'add_new' => __('Add New contact' ),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New contact' ),
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Contact',
            'new_item' => 'New Contact',
            'view_item' => 'View Contact',
            'search_items' => 'Search Contact',
            'not_found' => 'No contacts found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No contacts found in Trash'
            ),
    'public' => true,
    'menu_position' => 24,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-email',
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => __('contact')
    ),
    'supports' => array( 'title'),
));
}
```

Also have added below custom meta fields:

```
// Field Array  
$custom_meta_fields_contact = array(  
array(
    'label'=> __('Contact Name'),  
    'desc'  => 'Enter Contact Name here',  
    'id'    => 'contact_name',  
    'type'  => 'text'
),
array(
    'label'=> __('Contact Address'),  
    'desc'  => 'Enter Contact address here',  
    'id'    => 'contact_address',  
    'type'  => 'textarea'
),
array(
    'label'=> __('Contact No'),  
    'desc'  => 'Enter Contact number here',  
    'id'    => 'contact_no',  
    'type'  => 'text'
),
array(
    'label'=> __('Contact Email'),  
    'desc'  => 'enter contact email id here',  
    'id'    => 'contact_email',  
    'type'  => 'text'
),
);
```

I have added functions to show custom meta fields and save custom meta, which is OK and working.

Within this plugin I need to call contact_email meta field. For which I have added following code :

```
// get the Contact email address
$args_contact = array('post_type' => 'contact');

$contact_posts = new WP_Query($args_contact);
if($contact_posts->have_posts()) : 
    while($contact_posts->have_posts()) :   $contact_posts->the_post();
        $to = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'contact_email');
    endwhile;   endif;
wp_reset_query();
```

But whenever I am trying to get the value of $to inside the plugin , its returning nothing. Where as in the contact page am able to get and display contact_name, contact_number, contact_address and contact_email properly.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'contact_email', true);
```

OR declare global $post variable after if condition

```
if($contact_posts->have_posts()) : 
global $post;
```

Comment: thanks 4 the gr8 help. it worked. I had missed global declaration.